# Performance Issues with Dotnet Web API Load Testing

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-balancing, load-testing

We are performing load testing on Dotnet WebAPIs using Jmeter and also we have AWS load balancers.

The APIs in my cloud watch hardly takes 1s however in the Jmeter log it takes upto 30s.

The CPU isn't hitting >80%.

Not sure where is the bottleneck. Is it at the Jmeter or Load Balancers or WebAPI (highly unlikely).

We checked the metrics of Load Balancers and it does hit 30s response time.

Answer (score 0):

If resources consumption is definitely not the bottleneck the remaining possible reasons are:

1. Your WebAPI algorithms are not fully utilizing underlying machine's resources due to being not efficient enough and/or too complex in terms of [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)
2. You're hitting only one instance behind the load balancer, try [disabling DNS Caching](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420655--Disable-DNS-caching) or adding a [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to use a custom resolver.
3. JMeter is not sending requests fast enough due to lack of resources or improper configuration, make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if needed switch to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test)

Comment: We are trying to disable -- https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420655--Disable-DNS-caching . However didn't find the place to disable in Jmeter.

Comment: Add `sun.net.inetaddr.ttl=0` and/or `networkaddress.cache.ttl=0` to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and restart JMeter to pick up the change. More information: [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)